# How to change the system time of an Ubuntu server in command line as a non-root user?

Tags: linux

I want to change the system time of our Linux server (Ubuntu) in command line, but I am not the root user and I am not in sudoers also.
How can I make it?

Comment: i don't think it's possible, just try to contact the admin

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change it by whole hours, you can set the TZ environment variable and set the correct time zone. If the clock is generally wrong, then you will have to contact the admin.

Edit: Of course setting TZ will only affect the user for which it is set. System daemons etc will continue to use the configured time.

Comment: Thanks, dominikh. But I am just a fresh in linux, coult you explain how to set the TZ environment, or what I can just refer to myself?

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/set-environment-variable-linux/ seems to have a good description

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the BIOS clock from the BIOS. Depending on your configuration this might work.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug and has been resolved in latest version of Ubuntu. users could exploit sudo to change system time.

this is not possible 
by the command is 
sudo date --set "25 Sep 2013 15:00:00" for instance